# Where do I add custom field validation code for a modelform_factory shown to user with a generic class based view in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Suppose for "floorfield" below I want to add field validation to the following effect:
If user submitted floorfield value is less than 0, re-prompt the user to submit a new floorfield value greater than zero.

I've read through the django documents, looked for tutorials, and I'm putting a dent in the wall with my nogging trying to figure out how to implement the above behavior.

```
class Amodel(...):
    floorfield = integerfield()

class Amodel(CreateView):
    model = Amodel
    form_class = modelform_factory(Amodel, fields=("floorfield",))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, doing customizations (such as special field validation) requires you to make your own form and passing it as an argument to the `modelform_factory`.
You can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function)

```
class AModelForm(forms.Form):
    floorfield = forms.FloatField()
    def clean(self):
        if self.floorfield <= 0
            #return your errors here
        #return cleaned form here
```

And call it in your CreateView like this:

```
form_class = modelform_factory(Amodel, form=AModelForm)
```

Then the `.clean()` method of your form will trigger when you post to the create view and it passes the `form_valid()`.

Comment: Do I need to make any additional calls in clean() to make sure any default form and field validation also occurs?

Comment: Yeah, you need to call the parents `clean()` as well. [Docs are here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method) and [here is some more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom form as modelform_factory `form` argument, and override `clean_floorfield` so validation happens automatically.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Or you just define `floorfield` as `PositiveIntegerField` model field.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield

Comment: Where would I place the clean_floorfield function? In the custom form for Afield?

Comment: I think the simplest way is to use PositiveIntegerField. Seems like that's exactly what you want.